# Angular js directive : How to set selected value or default value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I created directive form controls (tesxt, select, radio). In directive I am passing a value that I want access in directive function and if this value is not set or empty then set default value from question (data._pageAttributes.defaultValue)

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="que in questions[$state.current.name]">
                        <div ng-if="que.QuestionData._fieldType === 'text'" >
                            <!-- {{answers[que.QuestionData._attributeName]}} -->
                            <text-control-dir data="que.QuestionData" default="94403"></text-control-dir>
                        </div>  
                        <div ng-if="que.QuestionData._fieldType === 'select'" >
                            <select-control-dir data="que.QuestionData" default="2016"></select-control-dir>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-if="que.QuestionData._fieldType === 'radio'" >
                            <radio-control-dir data="que.QuestionData"></radio-control-dir>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-if="que.QuestionData._fieldType === 'hidden' && que.QuestionData._attributeName != 'CBQ'" >
                            <hidden-control-dir data="que.QuestionData"></hidden-control-dir>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

controlDirective.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
            .module("autoQuote")
            .directive('textControlDir', [textControlDir])
            .directive('selectControlDir', [selectControlDir])
            .directive('radioControlDir', [radioControlDir])
            .directive('hiddenControlDir', [hiddenControlDir]);

    function textControlDir()
    {
        return {
            transclude: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                data: '=data',
                default: '=default'
            },
            template: "<div ng-transclude></div><label>{{data._text}} </label><input ng-model='answer.PC' type='text' name='{{data._attributeName}}' id='{{data._attributeName}}' value='' >"
            ,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs)
            {
                console.log('default');
                console.log(attrs.default);
                if(attrs.default == '')
                {
                    attrs.default = data._pageAttributes.defaultValue;
                }

            }
        };
    }

    function selectControlDir()
    {
        return {
            transclude: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                data: '=data'
            },
            template: "<div ng-transclude></div><label>{{data._text}} </label><select type='text' name='{{data._attributeName}}' id='{{data._attributeName}}' >\n\
<option ng-repeat='ans in data._answerOptions'>{{ans._promptText}}</option></select>"
            ,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs)
            {
                //console.log("scope.data.QuestionData", scope.data.QuestionData);
            }
        };
    }

    function radioControlDir()
    {
         return {
            transclude: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                data: '=data'
            },
            template: "<div ng-transclude></div><label>{{data._text}} </label><input type='radio' name='{{data._attributeName}}' id='{{data._attributeName}}' value='Yes' >\n\
\n\
<input type='radio' name='{{data._attributeName}}' id='{{data._attributeName}}' value='No' >\n\
"
            ,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs)
            {
                //console.log("scope.data.QuestionData", scope.data.QuestionData);
            }
        };
    }

    function hiddenControlDir()
    {
        return {
            transclude: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                data: '=data'
            },
            template: "<div ng-transclude></div><label>{{data._text}} </label><input type='hidden' name='{{data._attributeName}}' id='{{data._attributeName}}' value='' >"
            ,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs)
            {
                //console.log(scope.data);
            }
        };
    }

}());
```

CA.js file has all question and default value that we are looping for form questions.

In directive I want to write operation to check whether value passed in default attribute or not. if no then get value from question.que and set selected in input and select control.

```
 link: function (scope, element, attrs)
        {
            if(attrs.default == '')
            {
                attrs.default = data._pageAttributes.defaultValue;
            }

        }
```

but this is not working for me.
Here I have set default value hardcoded for text(Zip code)94403 and for Vehicle year 2016

For zip code : 94403 should be filled in input box and if not this is blank then 35004 (from CA.json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't set the default it will be `undefined` not an `empty string`

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs)
       {
           if(attrs.default)
           {
               attrs.default = scope.data._pageAttributes.defaultValue;
           }

       }
```

It will check both `empty` and `undefined`.

Comment: I updated plunker but getting error angular.js:13708 ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at Object.link.. I think data is not accessible insight link function of directive.

Comment: @Greatym.com, If the data is the directive property, you must access it with `scope.data`

Comment: I am stuck here, can you please look into the plunker link. you will get what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ng-model instead of default and set the value of the ng-model in your controller if the data corresponding to the HTML element is changed trhe ng-model will change automatically.

http://jsfiddle.net/halirgb/Lvc0u55v/

```
<input ng-model="example">
```